# Redefining a built-in operator

Tags: operators, custom-notation

Is there a way I can redefine the `||` operator such that `a||b` will be `1/(1/a + 1/b)`?

Is it possible to define it infix as above and prefix such that `||[a,b,c]` is `1/(1/a+1/b+1/c)`?

I'm working with circuit impedances and it's a much more natural way of describing the circuit to use `+` for series and something simple like `||` for parallel.

Comment: You *could*, but you're asking for a witches-brew of nastiness messing with it that way. Why not just define a single character function - perhaps using some preferred symbol with no built-in operation, e.g. `
p[a___] := 1/Tr@(1/{a})`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: If you follow @ciao's suggestion, you can also use it in infix notation via `a ~p~ b`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use upvalues. You don't want || to change its behavior except when it's operating on impedances. So, use a wrapper (z[ ], say) around the quantities that represent impedances, and associate upvalues with the wrapper. This lets you redefine how standard operators work on the wrapped values:

```
z[a_] || z[b_] ^= z[1/(1/a + 1/b)];
z[a_] + z[b_] ^= z[a + b];
a_ z[b_] ^= z[a b];

2 z[2] || z[1] + z[3]
(* z[2] *)
```

Comment: This sounds very much like what I'd like.  Time to go digging through the docs and figure out what upvalues  are...

Comment: I wound up going with the `DoubleVerticalBar` suggestions below, but this best answers the question I was asking in a safe way.  Is the preferred assignment operator `^=` or `^:=`?  Both seem to work, but I'm sure there must be a difference.

Comment: @Omegaman There is exactly the same difference that there is between `=` and `:=`. The `^` just stands there to signal that you want to associate the whole definition to the symbol `z` and not `||`. Define `f1[g1[t_]] ^= Expand[t^2]` and `f2[g2[t_]] ^:= Expand[t^2]` and run `f1[g1[t+1]]` and `f2[g2[t+1]]`. You can check why it does what it does by looking at `?g1` and `?g2`.

Answer (score 10):

I don't like the idea of redefining `Or` (`||`). Rather, I would suggest defining a function with the name `DoubleVerticalBar`.

There is a special double vertical bar character which will be interpreted as the infix operator for `DoubleVerticalBar` and can be input with <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>|</kbd>+<kbd>|</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

```
SetAttributes[
  DoubleVerticalBar, 
  {NumericFunction, Orderless, Flat, OneIdentity, Listable}]
DoubleVerticalBar[a_, 0] := a
DoubleVerticalBar[a_, b_] := 1/(1/a + 1/b)
```

Then you can do things like the following

[image: DblVerBar]

Comment: If need be, the function can of course be redefined to handle an argument of $0$, without it spitting out a warning message.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Good idea. I have acted on it.

Comment: This was suggested by @Karsten7 as a comment to another answer, and is what I'm currently implementing.  The SetAttributes call is quite helpful.  I'd also point out that if one argument is 0, the result should be zero in order to be consistent with the full definition (and, in this case, true parallel impedances).  You have my gratitude and upvote, but I think selecting this answer probably will confuse people in the future that search on the question as I (too) narrowly asked it.  Thank you though, you got me closer to my solution.

Comment: @Omegaman. I interpreted one argument being zero an meaning only one impedance was present rather than as a short circuit. But defining that case to be a short circuit makes a lot sense and is a trivial change the function: `DoubleVerticalBar[a_, 0] := 0`

Answer (score 7):

(I would love to hear from someone more knowledgeable about how to improve this answer.)

It is possible to redefine the `||` operator if you're willing to redefine the built-in `Or`, but I would certainly not recommend that because `Or` is a very common function upon which Mathematica probably relies internally all over the place.

Possibly more robust but still really scary is redefining the notation itself, using the `Notation` package. (This will look much nicer when pasted into Mathematica.)

```
mean[l___] := HarmonicMean[l]/Length[l]

<< Notation`

Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{"x_", "||", " ", "y_", " "}]] \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] 
  ParsedBoxWrapper[
   RowBox[List[" ", 
    RowBox[List["mean", "[", 
     RowBox[List["{", RowBox[List["x_", ",", "y_"]], "}"]], "]"]]]]]]
```

This will cause Mathematica to evaluate `mean[{a,b}]` instead of `Or[a,b]` when you type `a || b`.

A similar trick will let you use `||[a,b,c]`. It's extremely odd, I have no idea how robust it is, and Mathematica's syntax highlighting will have a fit, but it works. It also doesn't interfere with `Or`, that I can see.

```
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
  RowBox[{"||", 
  RowBox[{"[", 
  RowBox[{"a_", ",", "b_", ",", "c_"}], 
   "]"}]}]] \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow]
 ParsedBoxWrapper[
  RowBox[{" ", 
  RowBox[{"mean", "[", 
  RowBox[{"{", 
  RowBox[{"a_", ",", "b_", ",", "c_"}], "}"}], "]"}]}]]]
```

Then `|| [a, b, c]` will output `1/(1/a + 1/b + 1/c)`.

As I see ciao has commented above, it is really much better to define your own symbol.

Comment: In the words of the G-Man "...prepare for unforeseen consequences" - +1 on the answer and the appropriate cautions.

Comment: I guess I don't understand how Mathematica is implemented under the hood.  If I redefine the top-level symbol `||`, it will redefine `Or` the behavior as used by other built-ins?  I figured I'd lose the ability to use `||` at the top level but would retain access to `Or` and certainly wouldn't be able to disrupt internal implementations...

Comment: It's because the symbol `||` is translated immediately into `Or` before evaluation even takes place. It's just syntactic sugar. Either you have to change `Or`, or you have to change the mapping between `||` and `Or`. (It's the latter which I fleshed out above, using `Notation`.) EDIT: I mean "symbol" as distinct from `Symbol` - in the typographical sense rather than the Mathematica-construct sense.

Comment: One could avoid all the potential trouble by using [`\[DoubleVerticalBar]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/DoubleVerticalBar.html), which is displayed as `∥`, instead of `||`.

Comment: @Karsten7, that's the solution I went with.  Didn't actually answer the question I'd asked, but solved the problem I had.  Thanks!