# How to expand (not replace) the "+", ">" infix operator on strings?

Tags: operators

I went through the similar questions to overload the behavior of built-in operator, like [How to overload the operator "*" as KroneckerProduct](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116211/how-to-overload-the-operator-as-kroneckerproduct). The answers given there are usually to use new operator, instead of touching the built-in ones, as it might break how things work by default.

Defining a new infix operator works to a degree, especially at narrower context. But a remaining problem is there'll just be more and more different operators to be defined when the context expands. So I think a better way would be to re-use the existing ones if possible (give them new meaning for new context, without introducing ambiguity and breaking existing behaviors).

With that, I think of string. They're different from numbers, so is it possible to expand the behavior of built-in operators like "+" on strings? so that its behavior can be expanded when the operands are strings, and not breaking the default behavior:

```
In:= "ab" + "ac"

Out= "abac"

In:= 1 + 1

Out= 2

In:= "ab" > "ac"

Out= False

In:= 1 > 2

Out= False
```

Comment: Just saw another similar question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89706/redefining-a-built-in-operator, with mentioning of `upvalues`, might be helpful.

Comment: You can concatenate strings with `<>`. I would not try to overload `+` for this purpose. I believe that the risk that something will be severely broken by this change is very high.

Comment: `<>` works for string concatination. But the fact one has to use a different operator in different context is not ideal, as explained in the question. We'll just end up with a tons of different operators, and each works for a different purpose. I've updated the question description to cover more purposes to highlight this.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this?

```
Unprotect[Plus];
Plus[s__String] := StringJoin[s];
Protect[Plus];
```

Let's try:

"b" + "a"

> "ab"

Uh, it does not work because `Plus` has `Attribute` `Orderless` *and you definitely do not want to remove that*.

So no, it does not work.

Comment: Couldn’t you do something like have it not be `Orderless` when the arguments are strings?

Comment: Unfrotunately no. According to `?Orderless`, `Orderless` sorts the entries already _before_ pattern matching. So you cannot circumvent it by pattern matching.